# Inserting space at specific location in a string

Tags: r, string, tidyverse, stringr, stringi

I want to add white space after three character in a string. I used the following code which works well. I wonder if there is any other simple way to accomplish the same task

```
library(stringi)
Test <- "3061660217"
paste(
    stri_sub(str = Test, from = 1, to = 3)
  , stri_sub(str = Test, from = 4)
  , sep = " "
  )

[1] "306 1660217"
```

Comment: I think you could do something like `sub("^(.{3})", "\\1 ", Test)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using basic `regex` and `stringr`:

```
library(stringr)
str_replace(Test, pattern = "(.{3})(.*)", replacement = "\\1 \\2")
```

Output:

```
"306 1660217"
```

Same method works with base `R` as well:

```
gsub(Test, pattern = "(.{3})(.*)", replacement = "\\1 \\2")
```

**Explanation**:

1. `(.{3})` - find any 3 characters
2. `(.*)` - find any character 0 or more times
3. `\\1` - backreferences `(.{3})`
4. `\\2` - backreferences `(.*)`
5. The space between `\\1` and `\\2` is the space you want to add